# Diseño formulario MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Podrían ayudarme en pasarme un ejemplo de como crear un formulario MVC pero no el típico que van todos los `textbox` en una sola columna uno abajo del otro, sino necesito poner dos o tres controles (`textbox`, `radio`, `dropdown`, etc) en una misma linea horizontal.

Comment: Para que obtengas una mejor ayuda, te recomiendo que pongas algún trozo de código con el cual tienes problemas.

Comment: esto que planteas no tiene que ver con asp.net mvc sino con html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias usar el estilo `float:right`

[5.7. Posicionamiento flotante](http://librosweb.es/libro/css/capitulo_5/posicionamiento_flotante.html)

para que los controles se ubiquen uno al lado de otro

al ser controles de asp.net mvc deberias agregarlo como atributo

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>x.Prop1, new { Style="float:right;" })
```

Aunque recomendaria que uses alguna libreria que aplique estilos al sitio como ser [BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar bootstrap para crear tus formularios MVC. No solo porque contiene un gran numero de objetos para tus formularios, es responsive, y trabaja de maravilla con HTML5 y Razor. Actualmente tiene una gran presencia en la web y super fácil de instalar. Su sistema de Grid para alinear los objetos te ahorra lineas de CSS y HTML.

Abajo te dejo la pagina oficial de Bootstrap, ademas de un ejemplo de un simple login en un formulario responsive alineado horizontalmente. Puedes usar la librería directamente como el ejemplo que te muestro o mejor aun descargarla e instalarla en tu código. Si tienes visual Studio  puedes encontrarla con el Gestor de Nutget e instalarla.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

[Pagina Oficila bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo puedes generarlo con razor y alinearlo con bootstrap ya que MVC 5 trae integrado el framework. recuerda que razor es potente y tiene radiobutton, textbox, entre otros. puedes simplemente utilizarlos y agregarle las clases de bootstrap.